# git log foo..bar -- how to see *merge dates* for changesets?

Tags: git

Is it possible to get 'git log' to give the date *when a changeset landed on a branch* rather than the date when the changeset was created? 'git log --graph' (example truncated output below) gives me much of what I want, but it still prints the dates when the individual changesets were created rather than when they were merged into this branch.

```
*   commit 7e8d68fc58b915cc17bca41be833c4f7a062cd3c
|\  Merge: 1b4f10d af0dcdd
| | Date:   Wed Apr 25 17:40:16 2012 +0100
| |     Merge branch 'foo'
| * commit af0dcdd078197a852fcfad11c5111aa11579aa05
| | Date:   Wed Apr 25 17:36:50 2012 +0100
| |     t2: adding lorem ipsum again
| * commit 569f5de0eb40cbf198771812f9b099cf71b5b056
| | Date:   Wed Apr 25 17:36:36 2012 +0100
| |     t1: adding lorem ipsum
* | commit 1b4f10d3eea7c9c6304f7b1fd41818b932e4dad0
| | Date:   Wed Apr 25 17:38:24 2012 +0100
| |     t4: fi fo fa fum x 2
* | commit d25fa0359fbe655b6a4adeb6225ac283b3543ece
|/  Date:   Wed Apr 25 17:38:10 2012 +0100
|       t3: fi fo fa fum
* commit d3239b3e327f740fc7194ecf164538361f715ab5
  Date:   Wed Apr 25 17:34:50 2012 +0100
```

In the above the output is from the `master` branch. t1 and t2 were created on the `foo` branch; t3 & t4 were created on `bar`. Then `bar` was merged into `master` followed by merging `foo` into master.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can see part of the answer: When branch `foo` was merged into `master`, it created a new commit (7e8d68) with two parents.

But when `bar` was merged into `master`, it was a *fast-forward* merge. That is, all of the commits on `bar` were newer than the newest work on `master`, so they could just be tacked onto the end.

That makes for a simpler layout, and so it's the default behavior. But it leaves no record of the merge -- as far as your history is concerned, it will look like those commits were done on `master` in the first place.

To get around that, it's possible to tell git explicitly to avoid fast-forward merges: that is, every single merge should result in a merge commit with two parents, even if a fast-forward merge would be possible. To do that, just use the `--no-ff` flag on the `git merge` command.

Unfortunately, because that's a change in *merging* behavior rather than *logging* behavior, you won't be able to do it retroactively -- the information from your previous fast-forward merges doesn't exist, so there's no way to get `git log` to display it.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose I'll just have to use the `--graph` view to make sense of it...

Comment: Thank you very much Etaoin, this is exactly what I was looking for