# See when a merge happened

Tags: git, merge, version-control, git-merge

With this command

```
git branch --merged
```

I can see all the merges. For example

```
develop
  feature/az***_STAGING
  feature/az***_POC
  feature/az***_ricerche
  feature/az***_gp
  feature/patch_puntamento
  hotfix/az***_recupero
  prova_da_rinominare
```

But how can I see *when* branch was merged? For example

```
  feature/az***_STAGING     01/01/2022
  feature/az***_POC         15/03/2022
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320234/git-log-foo-bar-how-to-see-merge-dates-for-changesets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1441062/7559642 combined with `--merges` should do what you want:
`git log --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s" --merges`

Answer (score 0):

To spot the first merge commit that came after said branch, you can try :

```
git rev-list --merges --ancestry-path <branch_name>..master | tail -1

# to inspect the history of the above commit :
git log --oneline --graph <sha>

# or as a one liner :
git log --oneline --graph $(git rev-list ...)
```